# how to generate random data based on simple statistical meassures

Tags: dataset, monte-carlo, random-generation, javascript

0

I currently have a test data set that has 500k data points. I have an algorithm that process that data and returns some information. In order to establish the statistical significance of the results Id like to run a monte carlo simulation. I would do this by taking the:

- Kurtosis
- Std deviation
- Mean
- Skewness

And generating a series of randomized data sets, on which I would run my algorithm again.

How would I generated a data-set with the same number of data points that have the exact same kurtosis std deviation mean and skewness?

Comment: Related: [How to simulate data that satisfy specific constraints such as having specific mean and standard deviation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30303/7290)

Comment: Here are three R packages for simulating data with specified distributions and relationships: * [SimCorrMix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SimCorrMix/SimCorrMix)
* [SimMultiCorrData](https://github.com/AFialkowski/SimMultiCorrData)
* [simrel](https://simulatr.github.io/simrel/)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution and, if the applicability to this question is not obvious, read the first paragraph under "history."

Comment: Have you considered running a bootstrap? You can resample the data you already have and this should match the moments that you want. In fact, I think this is more credible than running a simulation because any simulation will make distributional assumptions that may change the performance of your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you assume a normal distribution (+ skew and kurtosis). 
If this is correct, you can use Fleishman's method.
In R you can use the PoisNonNor package and for SAS der is also code available online. For further reading I recommend:
 Fleishman, A. I. (1978). A method for simulating non-normal distributions. Psychometrika, 43(4), 521-532. 
Bishara, A. J., & Hittner, J. B. (2012). Testing the significance of a correlation with nonnormal data: comparison of Pearson, Spearman, transformation, and resampling approaches. Psychological methods, 17(3), 399.

Comment: How are you getting a normal distribution with skewness and kurtosis?

Comment: Maybe I just didn't express myself well, what I meant was a skewed normal distribution but I did not know what the adjective of kurtosis was, so I used the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to find the cumulative distribution function of your event, you can then sample random events according to that distribution using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)

Comment: The question is unclear. Your statement is correct but it is not clear that the OP can determine the exact cdf.

Comment: while I believe I could in theory calculate the cdf, I'm looking for  something simpler. As a clarification, this is to determine the statistical significance of a trading algorithm. I apply the strategy to some data and then I want to use montecarlo to determine the stat sig of the initial result, maybe my logic is flawed somewhere?