# If original data are available, should replication data be added and everything re-analysed (IPD) or is a meta-analysis better?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis, replicability

One common practice which increases the odds of obtaining spurious
results is to keep collecting observations after a preliminary
analyses are performed<sup>[1]</sup>. This occurs when the cutoff point for
collecting cases is set as the time when significance is reached.

Noting that, it seems that meta analyses are a valid way of combining
a variety of studies in a way that minimises overall error in the
parameter estimate. But I guess that it's also a result of not having
access to the original data.

***So my question is***, what if you *do* have access to the original data
from previous experiments? Is it better to do a meta analysis of the
results or to combine the data from the previous studies and run the
analyses again, apparently called individual participant data (IPD),?

My guess is that the latter is ill-advised [although some people do it](/q/29486/46134). For one, it appears to be
suspiciously close to the undefined cutoff point discussed in Simmons
et al. It also seems to go against other advice I have received on
this site regarding [dipping into the same data set multiple times](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100151/).

Note that in my particular case, I may have access to *summary* data of each participant in a study I replicated, not all data points collected for every participant. Essentially I may have access to means, totals, etc for each participant in a previous study.

---

[1]: see, for example, Simmons, J. P., Nelson, L. D., & Simonsohn, U. (2011). False-Positive Psychology: Undisclosed Flexibility in Data Collection and Analysis Allows Presenting Anything as Significant. *Psychological Science*, *22*(11), 1359–1366. doi:10.1177/0956797611417632

Answer (score 1):

As the linked post [How to conduct a meta-analysis using raw data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29486/how-to-conduct-a-meta-analysis-using-raw-data) mentions this is widely done. If there is a concern about doing this sort of sequential analysis one might look at some of the papers which have tried to put this into a sequential framework. For instance Wetterslev and colleagues in J Clin Epid [here](http://www.jclinepi.com/article/S0895-4356(07)00147-3/abstract) or a follow-up [here](http://www.jclinepi.com/article/S0895-4356(07)00369-1/abstract) and another one in IJE [here](http://ije.oxfordjournals.org/content/38/1/276.long). Some of these may be behind a paywall but they seem to be widely copied in multiple internet sites.